# Can MvcMailer use .aspx files instead of Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I recently installed Mvcmailer. Its default view engine has been set to Razor. I would like to know how (if possible) to switch it to ASP.NET View Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the Aspx scaffolder as a default mailer scaffolder. Use this:

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name Mailer -Scaffolder Mailer.aspx
```

Or you can simply use something like the following

```
Scaffold Mailer.aspx WelcomeMailer Welcome,Hello
```

Comment: Hey Thanx for the cool plugin. We using it and its pretty cool.